# Continuing a running number in Scala

Tags: scala

Feel free to edit the title of this post.

Given these:

```
case class Foo(amount: Int, running: Int)
val seed = List(Foo(10, 10), Foo(5, 15), Foo(10, 25))
val next = List(20, 10, 15)
```

How do I map `next` into `List(Foo(20, 45), Foo(10, 55), Foo(15, 70))` the Scala way? As you can see it continues the running number.

Comment: I do not understand what is the logic applied to compute the running number after the map.

Comment: I don't understand the logic either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple different approaches, both `scanLeft` based:

```scala
val initial = seed.map(_.amount).sum
next
  .zip(next.scanLeft(initial)(_ + _))
  .map((Foo.apply _).tupled)
```

and

```scala
val initial = Foo(0, seed.map(_.amount).sum)
next
  .scanLeft(initial){
    case (Foo(_, total), n) =>
      Foo(n, total + n)}
  .tail
```

you might also consider solving it using recursion.